# Why does React tell me that my Material Select input doesn't have a name?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm creating a new form with React and one of the inputs is a Material UI  input. The form works great, but the console shows a `Missing name at` warning when the form loads even though I've put a name both on the select input and the hidden input that Material UI creates.

```js
<FormControl variant="filled" className={classes.formControl} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
  <InputLabel id="dog-breed-label">Dog Breed</InputLabel>
  <Select
    label="Dog Breed"
    labelId="dog-breed-label"
    name="dogBreed"
    value={defaultDog.dogBreed}
    onChange={event => setBankAccount({ ...dogBreed, dogBreed: event.target.value })}
    inputRef={register({ required: true })}
    variant="filled"
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    inputProps={{ name: 'dogBreedInput' }}
    inputRef={register({ required: true })}
  >
    <MenuItem value="CHIHUAHUA">Chihuahua</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="LABRADOR">Labrador Retriever</MenuItem>
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Warning Message ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6BHR.png)):

```
Missing name at {node: input, value: undefined, focus: ƒ}focus: ƒ focus()node: inputvalue: undefined__proto__: Object 
    in SelectInput (created by InputBase)
    in InputBase (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(InputBase)) (created by FilledInput)
    in FilledInput (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(FilledInput)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(FilledInput)) (created by Select)
    in Select (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Select)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Select)) (at modal.js:95)
    in Modal (at bankInformation/​index.js:146)
    in Anonymous (at demographics/​index.js:199)
    in Anonymous (at routes/​index.js:16)
```

What do I need to add to avoid seeing this warning in the console?

Comment: Please provide a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces this issue. I do not see the warning here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dog-breed-select-fibt5.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. I realized it actually happens in conjunction with react-hook-form. Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dog-breed-select-31nkr)

Comment: I think you may have forgotten to save changes in your sandbox. Changes are reflected in the output for the person editing it even before you save, but if you don't save, no one else will see those changes. When I look at your sandbox, I don't see any warning and it isn't using react-hook-form.

Comment: You're right, apologies. I've saved it now. I've been looking further just now, and it seems to be a support issue. It's been genereally addressed [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18269) but I'd still like to think there's some way to register my components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using react-hook-form version 4, I would recommend using Controller:

https://react-hook-form.com/api/#Controller

and the following code demonstrate the usage:

```
<Controller 
  control={control}
  name="dogBreed"
  as={<Select
    label="Dog Breed"
    labelId="dog-breed-label"
    value={defaultDog.dogBreed}
    variant="filled"
    style={{ width: '100%' }}
    inputProps={{ name: 'dogBreedInput' }}
  >
    <MenuItem value="CHIHUAHUA">Chihuahua</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="LABRADOR">Labrador Retriever</MenuItem>
  </Select>}
/>
```

---

also, your example have two register method in the props as well.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work. These plugins keep getting updated and breaking it's impossible to keep up. I'm using react-hook-form and material ui. I'm seeing the warning on load and on every keystroke.

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
        <InputLabel style={{color: !!errors[name] ? '#f44336' : ''}}>{label}</InputLabel>
        <Controller
            control={control}
            name={name}
            as={
                <Select
                    value={value}
                    name={name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    label={label}
                    inputProps={{
                        name: name,
                        ref: register({
                            required: 'Required field',
                        })
                    }}
                    error={!!errors[name]}
                >
                    <MenuItem value="">
                        <em>None</em>
                    </MenuItem>
                    {options.map((key, i) =>
                        <MenuItem key={i} value={key.value}>{key.label}</MenuItem>
                    )}
                </Select>
            }
            rules={{ required: required && "Required field" }}
            defaultValue=""
        />
        <FormHelperText style={{color:'#f44336'}}>
            {!!errors[name] ? <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name={name}/> : ''}
        </FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
```